# Moving the contents of one text file to the end of another

Tags: windows, command-line

How to ***append*** the contents of one text file (file1.txt) to another (file2.txt), and to delete the contents of the first file but ***still keeping it*** empty using command line tools?

Is there a way to do it, or do I have to resort to other means?

Ideally, it would be best if it could be done using command line tools on Windows XP platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
C:\>type file1.txt >>file2.txt <ENTER>
C:\>echo.>file1.txt  <ENTER>
```

Only thing is file1.txt has a new line in it and is not 0 bytes. You could replace that second command i.e. `echo.>file1.txt` with  `type nul>file1.txt` then file1.txt would be really empty, 0 bytes.

Comment: file1.txt has a dot inside?

Comment: no, the dot there is not literal. "echo."  makes a new line.  echo with nothin to echo, i.e. just plain "echo", would output "Echo is on." and funnily enough you can use some other punctuation marks instead of dot such as ( or = or /

Comment: No, it is quite literal in my case. Upon opening a file with an editor, there is a dot inside. Dot, as in full stop. But, never mind. I think it solved my problem ...

Comment: @ldigas strange, when I at the cmd line in xp do echo.. it displays .(dot)  but echo. (echodot) just does a new line.

Comment: @Idigas, did you put a space between echo and the dot?

Answer (score 1):

To append it, you can do as barlop suggested if they are plain text:

```
C:\> echo.>> file2.txt     :: If you want to add a blank line between them
C:\> type file1.txt >> file2.txt
```

Or if it is binary and/or has *any* non-text characters in it (eg Unicode, UTF-8, etc.):

```
C:\> copy /b file1.txt + file2.txt file.tmp
C:\> del file1.txt
C:\> ren file.tmp file1.txt
```

Now a reliable way (in DOS and Windows at least up to 7) to zero out the second file:

```
C:\> ren > file2.txt
or
C:\> ren > file2.txt 2> nul   :: to hide the error message (Windows only)
```

Comment: that ren line gives "The syntax of the command is incorrect."  and if you meant rem > file2  that doesn't create the file. doesn't work, though also, I hadn't heard of it either.. You're probably right given that you can write an exe in assembly language in notepad.. so be interesting to see how to zero out the file with that line!

Comment: Nope, it’s `ren` not `rem`. You can hide the error message by redirecting it to nul.

Comment: amazing, where did you read/hear about that? or did you discover it yourself by accident?

Comment: No idea. It’s just something I’ve been doing forever. I even wrote a little program (`newfile.exe`) years ago that simply creates a file (or zeros-out an existing one), and yet I always seem to catch myself using `ren` instead.

Comment: +1 particularly for the use of ren! and if you remembered how you ran into or discovered it, and I could, i'd give another +1 for it!

Comment: Nope, I have no idea how I figured that out; I’ve been using this trick for a long time. My best guess is that I noticed it by accident while messing around with batch files way back when (probably while trying to get one to work correctly).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
type file1.txt >> file2.txt && echo. > 1.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

How about just use [unixutils for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command).

And then do the append/touch stuffs just like you work on unix.

Comment: I can resort to DOS, but that's it. Specifically asked for cmd or DOS, for a reason.